# Writing a more efficient attribute selector function

Tags: jquery, attributes, parent

Is there a better way of writing this code:

http://jsfiddle.net/2u7fg/2/

```
$('img').filter(function() { return $(this).attr('align').length > 0; }).parent().css('background', 'red');
```

The goal is to select all image elements on the page that have an 'align' attribute and apply a style to the parent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('img[align]').parent().css('background', 'red');
```

there you go :)

http://jsfiddle.net/2u7fg/3/

Answer (score 3):

You can filter using the following syntax, specifying the matching element(s) must have an 'align' attribute:

```
$('img[align]').parent().css('background','red');
```